# Angular, Using Elvis sing in [(ngModel)] with mat-form-field

Tags: angular, angular-material, ngmodel, mat-form-field

I want to achieve when object or id is null don't show anything, be empty so when user want to update, it can do it later on..

```html
<mat-form-field appearance="legacy">
  <mat-label>LOCATION</mat-label>
    <mat-select name="obj"  [(ngModel)]="exampleObj.obj.id" >
      <ng-container *ngFor="let obj of objs">
      <mat-option [value]="obj.id">
        {{obj.location}}
      </mat-option>
    </ng-container>
  </mat-select>
</mat-form-field>
```

The error is ctx.exampleObj.obj is null.

The Elvis sing (?) doesn't work with mat-form-field.

Can someone please help me?

Comment: Welcome to stack overflow. At which line u are getting "ctx.exampleObj.obj is null" error ?
what is your `objs` ? do u mind sharing it ?

Comment: Tnx...  I'm getting error on exampleObj.obj.id...
objs is array of objects, it has fields like id, location.
There are situations when obj doesnt exist in database so i want that to be empty field

Answer (score 0):

I fixed it. Just added an empty string in properties of obj. for example:

```
obj = { id : ' ' , location : ' ' }
```